# How does the Hunter Playtonic work?

Tags: yooka-laylee

```
Hunter - A sound effect is made when near rare items.
```

Source : http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Play_Tonics

What are the items that are considered rare? Also, what is the sound effect that I should be expecting?

Comment: The sound effect is a catcall/wolf-whistle, which is strange considering how a simple "heads up"/"over here" whistle would have been more fitting (in b4 wolf joke)

Comment: Good description of the sound effect :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will hear a whistling sound when you are near a rare item.  If you are using a controller, it will also vibrate.

The rare items are:

- Power Extenders
- Mollycools
- Butterfly Boosters
- [Pirate Treasures](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Treasure)

Sources:

[Tank War Room](http://tankwarroom.com/article/713/yooka-laylee-how-to-unlock-all-tonics) and experience using the tonic.

**Edit:** I've also noticed that quills will trigger the effect.  However, it appears you have to have only a few remaining before the whistling sound is heard.  This is likely to make it easier to find those last few quills.  I'm not sure how many remaining is needed in order to hear the sound, but I've observed it with only four left.

Comment: What the hell is a pirate treasure?

Comment: @Fredy31 [see this](https://www.destructoid.com/yooka-laylee-guide-locations-of-all-five-secret-pirate-treasures-430549.phtml).

Comment: @Fredy31 I also hyperlinked the Pirate Treasure text in the answer.

Comment: Came to comment exactly what the edit was. It seems that when you have maybe 20 quills left to get the quills will also be considered rare.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must have less than 30 quills remaining on a world for the hunter tonic's whistle to start working. This is still relatively unhelpful as the whistle doesnt sound until you're pretty darn close to the quill or other item, but 30 quills or less it is! This also applies to tokens, in the Capital Cashino world.